# v8::Persistent MarkIndependent, what does this method exactly do?

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

Following is v8 code comment, I don't quite understand explaination.

```cpp
/**
 * Marks the reference to this object independent. Garbage collector
 * is free to ignore any object groups containing this object.
 * Weak callback for an independent handle should not
 * assume that it will be preceded by a global GC prologue callback
 * or followed by a global GC epilogue callback.
 */
inline void MarkIndependent();
inline void MarkIndependent(Isolate* isolate);
```

Answer (score 1):

From a [post on v8-users](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/v8-users/IZf833AD9O0/0PJ_F0RzAAAJ):

> I think the exact meaning of 'independent' has shifted a little since 
>   3.24.  Here is my understanding of what it does in recent versions of  V8:
>
> 1. It avoids the cost of object group handling.  We don't use object  groups in node.js but I think chromium does for DOM objects; if one 
>      DOM object in the collection is alive, then logically all are. 
>      Defining an object group lets the garbage collector take a shortcut at
>      a cost of some processing overhead per individual handle.
> 2. Independent handles can be reclaimed during minor garbage  collections (scavenges).  Dependent handles are only reclaimed during 
>      major collections and thus remain alive longer, which is usually 
>      undesirable; I think they only become eligible for collection once the
>      object they point to has been promoted from the new space (the 
>      nursery) to the old space.